# How do I import this OPA313 PSpice model into LTspice?

Tags: ltspice, pspice, model

It's been asked quite a few times how to import PSpice models into LTspice but none of the methods seem to apply to this particular model from TI. I really don't understand what all these files are inside the .zip. Isn't there supposed to be a .lib file somewhere which we can link to a component?

[Here](https://www.ti.com/product/OPA2313#design-tools-simulation) is a model for the OPA313 if you follow the link and scroll down a bit.

Under sbomaq3b\opa313-PSpiceFiles\SCHEMATIC1\transient there is a .cir file which my computer seems to think is an LTspice netlist file. Opening it in LTspice gives me this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model is in the root directory of the archive. Use opa313.lib.

[image]

Comment: This worked. Thank you. For some reason my windows computer does not recognize that as a .lib file. After opening it in LTspice now, it's identifying it as a an altium library file. Very interesting. I also followed these steps: https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-simple-steps-to-import-third-party-models.html

Comment: @BobaJFET  You shouldn't assume only files which claim an association with LTspice are the only ones that can be used within LTspice. For example, SPICE models from OnSemi might have a `.SP3` extension which will work in LTspice.  If the manufacturer ships a bunch of different files, of course try opening the `.LIB` first using the method in step 1 of the article you linked.  If that's not it, start trying others until you file a `.MODEL` or `.SUBCKT` statement near the top of the text.  Also, if you haven't already you should tell your Windows OS to always show file extensions.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/205086/beginner-how-to-make-windows-show-file-extensions/